# Raster layer - changing values in raster cells

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have a lot of cells in a raster layer (GeoTIFF) with a -9999 value in it. I would like to update that values to 0.

I mean, in vectorial layers would be something like: CASE WHEN band1=-9999 THEN 0 ELSE band1 END

Is this possible to do for raster layers in QGIS or any other GIS software?

Comment: I am not sure but do you need something like reclass? eg. in grass gis you can reclass like: -9999 = 0 , * = *. The * = * means that the other values remain same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it using the following expression y QGIS Raster Calculator:

("rasterlayer" != -9999) * "rasterlayer"